# Проблемы с кодировкой (но это не точно)

Tags: java, javafx, кодировка, utf-8

Всем привет. Возникли проблемы с кодировкой. IDE NetBeans 7.2. Вроде как использую UTF-8.

Когда создаю файл- ячейку в таблице до компиляции, ее не показывает после компиляции. А если открыть среду разработки, то ситуация наоборот. Файлы которые были созданы в программе после компиляции не видит. А которые были созданы в среде все видит.

вот картиночки:

это отображает в NetBeans. Сверху ячейки созданы в нетбине, снизу уже после компиляции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это отображает после компиляции:
ячейки которые были созданы в нетбине не отображает, точней отображает, но зябры козябры.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страшен ли такой баг для юзверей? Или это норма.
Я предполагаю что кодировка по умолчанию в нетбине мб не та и пишет вот это.
Код силен в кодировках подскажите пж.

Немного поковырялся. В NetBeans записывает в UTF-8. 
В .jar без какой-либо кодировки.
Запись файлов в программе без указания кодировки:

```
try(PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileResume))) {
                    writer.write(s1);
                    writer.append("\n");
}
```

вот чтение файлов:

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(globalFile))) {
                    while(scanner.hasNext()) 
                    stringBuffer.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");
}
```

Около 2-х часов копался, нашел решение:

код для записи:

```
try(PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileResume), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true)) {
                        writer.write(s1);
                        writer.append("\n");
}
```

Код для чтения:

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(globalFile), "UTF-8")) {
                        while(scanner.hasNext()) 
                        stringBuffer.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");
}
```

Comment: похоже что строки находятся в разных кодировках, поэтому ваш код не может справиться с кодировкой.